# Не обрабатываются стили, хотя путь правильный

Tags: php, html, css

столкнулся с такой проблемой. Подключил все нужные css стили, через Инструменты разработчика проверил, путь написан правильно, но он не отображается

```html
<?php 
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['user']) {
        header('Location: user-authorize.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="assets/main.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="assets/profile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="assets/vacansy.css" />
    <title>Мой профиль</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="profile">
            <div class="user-side-greetings">
                <div class="user-profile-image" style="background-image: url(<?= $_SESSION['user']['avatar'] ?>);"></div>
                <div class="profile-nav">
                    <h2>Здравствуйте, <?= '' . $_SESSION['user']['surname'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['user']['name'] . ''?>!</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><p><a href="#">Просмотреть работодателей</a></p></li>
                        <li><p><a href="#">Изменить свою вакансию</a></p></li>
                        <li><p><a href="vendor/logout.php">Выход</a></p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="user-vacansy">
                <h2>Так выглядит ваша вакансия:</h2>
                <div class="vacansy">
                    <div class="vacansy-content">
                        <div class="vacansy-text">
                            <h3 class="vacansy-profession"><?= $_SESSION['user']['profession'] ?></h3>
                            <p><b>Дата размещения:</b> 12 декабря в 12:20</p>
                            <p><b>Опыт работы: </b><?= $_SESSION['user']['work_exp'] ?></p>
                            <p><b>Возраст:</b> <?= $_SESSION['user']['age'] ?></p>
                            <p><b>О себе:</b> <?= $_SESSION['user']['about'] ?></p>
                            <h4>Контакты:</h4>
                            <p><b>Телефон:</b> <a href="tel:89150885431" class="vacansy-contact-href"><?= $_SESSION['user']['tel'] ?></a></p>
                            <p><b>Почта:</b> <a href="pantheleymonbbx@yandex.ru" class="vacansy-contact-href"><?= $_SESSION['user']['email'] ?></a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="vacansy-image">
                            <img src="<?= $_SESSION['user']['avatar'] ?>"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Если папка `/assets` находится __там же__ где и данный `.php` файл, тогда путь правильный.

Comment: Конфиг веб сервера и расположение файлов в студию

Comment: Кеш очистил? Или зайди через режим инкогнито Ctrl+Shift+N

Comment: С путями всё правильно, ошибок нет, тоже подозреваю в правильности работы локальный сервер. Так как я на MAC, веб-сервер стоит Mamp, однако все остальные страницы и весь сайт отображается правильно

Comment: PHP - серверный язык. Осмелюсь предположить, что сервер, на котором вы запускаете свой сайт, по-умолчанию блокирует любые запросы (CORS). Посмотрите на наличие подобных ошибок в консоли. Во всяком случае, если стили не загружаются, значит что-то мешает им загрузиться. Попробуйте настроить сервер.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="assets/main.css" /> загружает стили по относительному адресу. То есть если адрес страницы /profile/index.php, то стиль браузер ищет по адресу /profile/assets/main.css. Если стиль находится по адресу /assets/main.css, то нужно писать <link rel="stylesheets" type="text/css" href="/assets/main.css" /> - со слэшем в начале.

Comment: Собственно, нужно увидеть структуру папок и файлов, чтобы дать точный ответ. Скрин в студию)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема была в `rel="stylesheets"`, s на конце оказалась лишней.